# Apache Spark Scala : groupbykey maintains order of values in input RDD or not

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

May be i am asking very basic question apology for that, but i didn't find it's answer on internet. Is groupBykey maintains order of values. Value which occur first in input RDD should come first in the Output RDD. I tried this and it is mainlining that order, but i wanted to confirm that from expert. I need something like below

```
Input RDD [Int, Int]
 1 20
 2 10
 1 8
 1 25

Output RDD
 1 20 8 25
 2 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

> Group the values for each key in the RDD into a single sequence. Hash-partitions the resulting RDD with the existing partitioner/parallelism level. The ordering of elements within each group is not guaranteed, and may even differ each time the resulting RDD is evaluated.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions@groupByKey():org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(K,Iterable[V])]

Comment: Can you suggest what can be done to accomplish the result.

Comment: That's another question, make a new one. Did you consider sorting? Maybe with zipWithIndex.